# How to Process a ArrayList in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, timestamp

I have made a arraylist `type - JSONObject`. Now what I want to do is, As you can see there are similer timestamps. I want to get the values of similar timestamps and check whether all the values are 1. if yes, get the output as 1. else as 0.

and do the same thing for all the timestamps and generate a JSON with all the timestamps.

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "unit": "up/down",
        "datapoints": [
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445000000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445060000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445120000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445180000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445240000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445300000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445360000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445420000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445480000
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1580445540000
          }
        ],
        "isString": false,
        "externalId": "3D_Uptime_Rate",
        "id": 4924875616701448,
        "isStep": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "unit": "up/down",
        "datapoints": [
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445000000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445060000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445120000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445180000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445240000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445300000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445360000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445420000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445480000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445540000
          }
        ],
        "isString": false,
        "externalId": "3D1",
        "id": 4924875616701448,
        "isStep": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "unit": "up/down",
        "datapoints": [
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445000000
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1580445060000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445120000
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1580445180000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445240000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445300000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445360000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445420000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445480000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445540000
          }
        ],
        "isString": false,
        "externalId": "3D2",
        "id": 4924875616701448,
        "isStep": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Anyway finally I want to generate something like this;

```
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "unit": "up/down",
        "datapoints": [
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445000000
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1580445060000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445120000
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1580445180000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445240000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445300000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445360000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445420000
          },
          {
            "value": 1,
            "timestamp": 1580445480000
          },
          {
            "value": 0,
            "timestamp": 1580445540000
          }
        ],
        "isString": false,
        "externalId": "Union_Uptime",
        "isStep": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What did you mean "_the values of similar timestamps_"? Did you want to check all the values of the **same** timestamps? And what's your expected output? Please show us! BTW, please also provide a clearer example because all the values are 1 in your input JSON string.

Comment: Do you want to check all timestamps in all jsobobjects and return 1 or 0? or you want to check one objet at a time for all timestamps inside it?

Comment: @LHCHIN yes. I want ti check all the values of the same time stamp. I have edited the question and added the expected outcome. Hope that is clear now. Thanks :)

Comment: @VinitPillai - Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question and added the expected outcome. Hope that is clear now. Really sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct way is to covert the input JSON string to nested objects, then check all the values of `timestamp` field and store the result into a `Map`. Finally, generate the objects for output as follows:

**Step 1**
Create nested POJOs for deserialization and serialization from/to JSON string.

```
class Root {
    private List<Item> items;
    //general getters and setters
}

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class Item {
    private String unit;
    private List<DataPoint> datapoints;
    private boolean isString;
    private String externalId;
    private String id;
    private boolean isStep;
    //general getters and setters
}

class DataPoint {
    private int value;
    private Timestamp timestamp;
    //general getters and setters
}
```

**Step 2**
Deserialize JSON string to declared objects.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Root> root = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<List<Root>>(){});
```

**Step 3**
Create a `Map` to store the checked results.

```
Map<Timestamp, Integer> dataPointMap = new HashMap<>();
root.forEach(e -> {
    e.getItems().forEach(e1 -> {
        e1.getDatapoints().forEach(e2 -> {
            if (dataPointMap.containsKey(e2.getTimestamp())) {
                if (dataPointMap.get(e2.getTimestamp()) != 0) {
                    dataPointMap.put(e2.getTimestamp(), e2.getValue());
                }
            } else {
                dataPointMap.put(e2.getTimestamp(), e2.getValue());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Step 4**
Generate the aggregated objects for serialization.

```
List<DataPoint> datapoints = new ArrayList<>();
dataPointMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint();
    dataPoint.setTimestamp(k);
    dataPoint.setValue(v);
    datapoints.add(dataPoint);
});

Item item = new Item();
item.setUnit("up/down");
item.setDatapoints(datapoints);
item.setIsString(false);
item.setExternalId("Union_Uptime");
item.setIsStep(true);

List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(item);

Root rootOut = new Root();
rootOut.setItems(items);
```

**Step 5**

```
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(rootOut));
```

Comment: @Knight95 Please let me know if my solution helps you, thanks!